# Can't register callback url - Watson Speech to text API

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, watson

I have been working with the Watson speech to text API without an issue for 2 months, but today a problem came while trying to register a callback url, the curl request is as follows:

curl -X POST -u "{my-usernanem}":"{my-password}" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/register_callback?callback_url=https://www.google.com"

and the traceback:

{"code":400,"code_description":"Bad Request","error":"unable to register callback url 'https://www.google.com', callback server responded with status code 400"}

I am using google.com to ilustrate that it isn't making the get request, in my app I use another URL and when I check the logs there isn't a request to the specified URL, i.e. it is not trying to whitelist it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi Jose, we found this issue today and fixed it right away, can you please try again. It should work normally now.

Comment: @jose - Is your issue fixed?

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot!